# How do I test component that uses react context API?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have this app here: [link to codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-cori-0jn8w)
It fetches popular movie titles.

How do I test that onClick the api function is triggered and results are rendered? I want to use jest and testing-library/react.

I get this message regarding 'act' helper function. How do I work around that?

Answer (score 2):

Don't worry about the `act` warning. It's going to get fixed in the next version of React. See [here](https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/issues/281) for more info.

To test a component that uses a context simply render it within your context provider. In your case:

```
render(
  <Provider>
    <App />
  </Provider>
)
// Now interact with your component and
// check that the DOM changes correctly
```

I wrote a bit [here](https://www.polvara.me/posts/mocking-context-with-react-testing-library/) on how to test a context